# how use having count (distinict (col1, col2 )) >2 to get records fulfill any 2 or more conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct, having

How can I use `HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT (col1, col2)) >2 in sql  to find out those users`  who have any 3 following records  or more

```
SELECT user_id FROM users_responses 
WHERE 
(question_id = 3 AND response_id = 6)
OR(question_id = 7 AND response_id = 18)
OR(question_id = 1 AND response_id = 5)
OR(question_id = 8 AND response_id = 22)
OR(question_id = 2 AND response_id = 3)

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT question_id, response_id) > 2 ;
```

I have total 10 different users in this table with same and different responses. 3 users have exact responses are given above and 3 users fulfill 4 conditions while others users have only1-2 same responses given in query.

I need to fetch all those distinct user_id from this table who have responded to above question id and have same responses.

I tried but it gives only first record

Table structure

```
Id  |  user_id   |  question_id  |  response_id
```

Any idea how to make changes to get it work properly.

Comment: can you show us an example? but if you want `HAVING` you need `GROUP BY`

Comment: I wrote above query to fetch result which is giving the wrong result, what example you are asking me. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: sample data, and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: thanks , by using group by it's working @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Good, because I didnt understand the question :P

Comment: :P  I will improve this question to help others and will follow the instructions about How to Ask . thanks